# Where did the view handler design pattern come from?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out the origin of the view handler design pattern in software engineering. Many of the design patterns in software engineering were inspired by things which pre-date computers, and I was wondering if anybody had any insights on the origin of this particular pattern.

Comment: Can you provide any further information about the pattern? Maybe it is better known under other name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels a lot like a rule systems for updating construction or planning drawing dependencies. Or to rephrase, it seems like an automation of the work rules and cross-indexes required to keep a set of architectural plans synchronized as changes are made on each drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Look in POSA1 - Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture Volume 1: A System of Patterns (from 1996 i think).
There is a chapter about view handler. There are examples of the usage of a such pattern in 1985 (Macintosh Window Manager) and 1993 (Ms Word).

But i am not sure we are talking about the same pattern. Where you heard about this pattern name?